# Convert UTC time to local time BEFORE page is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table on my page. It has time column. Time in my HTML is stored as UTC string. I created javascript function which converts time cell from UTC time to local time. It is trivial, and everything is okay here.

I want to call this function before browser shows cells to end-user. Is it possible? As I understand, if I call it in `$(document).ready(....)`, the page is displayed already, so end-user may see some flicking. Am I correct?

Is it possible to call it right after cell is fully loaded to DOM, but before it is rendered?

What about if I will add `<script>` block right after each `td`? Will be it executed before cell is displayed? Your opinions please.

Comment: If you want my opinion, try it the normal, easy `$(document).ready()` way and only try to 'fix' it if you actually see a flicker. It seems like you haven't implemented it yet so you might be fixing a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: This would really be something best done on the server side. Do you have any way to do it there?

Comment: @hamstu, yes. Is it possible to get user local time in ASP.NET? All browser sends it? Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Set the cell or even the table to `display:none;`, fix it, then show it:

```
<td><span id="timecell" style="display:none;">My Time</span></td>
```

And then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // lots of other stuff
  var timecell = $("span#timecell"), initialVal = timecell.html(),
  newval = trasnform(initialVal);
  timecell.html(newval);
  timecell.show();
  // and lots of other stuff
});
```

Comment: What is `transform`? How is it relevant to OP's question?

Comment: @Jeff `transform` is his own function. I don't care how he transforms it, just that the cell is initially hidden, and that he does the transform *after* the DOM is ready, and then changes the cell contents and shows it.